# By how many pH units does rain vs distilled water change a soil pH test?

Tags: acid-base, ph

Sources state that the concentration of $\ce{H2CO3}$ in rain is of a few µmol; I don't know if that's per ml. The buffering effect of most soils is >1000 µmol $\ce{H+}$/kg.

Is the difference from low acid rain water versus lab distilled water on a pH test for soil less than 0.1 in pH values?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pure water (rain as well as distilled water) in equilibrium with the atmosphere ($p_{\ce{O2}}=10^{-3.5}\ \mathrm{atm}$) can be calculated to contain about
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{pH}=-\log[\ce{H+}]&=5.65\\
-\log[\ce{HCO3-}]&=5.65\\
-\log[\ce{CO3^2-}]&=10.3\\
-\log[\ce{H2CO3^*}]&=5.0\\
-\log[\ce{CO2}]&=5.0\\
-\log[\ce{H2CO3}]&=7.8\\
\end{align}$$

(The calculation can be found in: Stumm, W.; Morgan, J. J. *Aquatic Chemistry,* Third Edition; John Wiley & Sons: New York, NY, 1996; pp 159–161.)

Note that $[\ce{H2CO3^*}]$ is the total analytical activity of dissolved $\ce{CO2}$, i.e. $[\ce{H2CO3^*}]=[\ce{CO2(aq)}]+[\ce{H2CO3}]$. $[\ce{H2CO3}]$ is the concentration of true $\ce{H2CO3}$.

Thus, $[\ce{H2CO3^*}]=10^{-5}$ and $c(\ce{H2CO3^*})=10^{-5}\ \mathrm{mol/l}$; i.e. a few µmol/l.